# During setup of peer cli in hyperledger fabric, getting Endorsement failure error. Did anyone face this issue, how can this be resolved?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-java

On executing 'peer chaincode invoke' as per the documentation for fabric, getting the error 'Error: endorsement failure during invoke. response: status:500 message:"Undefined contract called"'.
I have checked packages and instantiated list:
peer lifecycle chaincode queryinstalled
Installed chaincodes on peer:
Package ID: basic_1.0:768b98e4408cc16f3ed5dcec186c25069801ec09441cba3b79bb316a0809632a, Label: basic_1.0

peer chaincode list --instantiated -C mychannel
Get instantiated chaincodes on channel mychannel:

Did anyone have same issue? How to resolve it?

I have run the given EXPORT commands before the chaincode invoke as per the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

you can confirm the contracts present

```
peer chaincode query -C mychannel -n basic -c '{"Args":["org.hyperledger.fabric:GetMetadata"]}'
```